# TypeScript NodeJS TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm new to TS so I don't know why it's spitting that error

VanillaJS version works just fine.
transferred it to TypeScript.
The error is in my index.ts.
compiling the TS code using tsc command is still the same.
if I use the console.log(this.server) in the constructor() outputs the object normally
but when I use the console.log(this.server) on the theListening() it's saying undefined its weird.

app.ts file

```
import * as express from 'express'
import * as http from 'http'
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
import * as path from 'path'
import indexRoutes from './routes/index'
import userRoutes from './routes/users'

class App {

  public express

  constructor () {
    this.express = express()
    this.middleware()
    this.mountRoutes()
    this.errorHandler()
  }

  private middleware(): void {
    this.express.use(bodyParser.json())
    this.express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

    this.express.use(cookieParser())
    this.express.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
  }

  private mountRoutes(): void {
    this.express.use('/', indexRoutes)
    this.express.use('/users', userRoutes)
  }

  private errorHandler(): void {
    this.express.use((req, res, next) => {
      let err:any = new Error('Not Found') // I don't know why the err var needs the :any type to work with err.status below it. Without the :any type err.status is spitting errors hahaha
      err.status = 404
      next(err)
    });

    this.express.use((err, req, res, next) => {
      res.locals.message = err.message
      res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {}

      res.status(err.status || 500)
      res.json({
        message: 'Error'
      })
    })
  }
}

export default new App().express
```

index.ts file

```
import app from './app'
import * as debug from 'debug'
import * as http from 'http'

class Server {

 public server

 public port

 public debug

constructor () {
  this.debug = debug('myexpress:server')
  this.port = this.normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000')
  app.set('port', this.port)
  this.server = http.createServer(app)
  this.server.listen(this.port)
  this.server.on('error', this.onError)
  this.server.on('listening', this.onListening)
}

private normalizePort(val): any {
  let port = parseInt(val, 10)

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    return val
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    return port
  }

  return false
}

private onError(error): void {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error
  }

  let bind = typeof this.port === 'string' ? 'Pipe ' + this.port : 'Port' + 
     this.port

  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges')
      process.exit(1)
      break

    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use')
      process.exit(1)
      break

    default:
      throw error
  }
}

public onListening(): void {
    let addr = this.server.address() << THIS RIGHT HERE

    let bind = typeof addr === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + addr : 'port ' + 
    addr.port

    debug('Listening on ' + bind)
  }
}

new Server()
```

Comment: you are having trouble with the scope of `this`, check Lostfields answer

Answer (score 1):

first, when using .on (listeners) bind your method to the right scope.

```
this.server.on('listening', this.onListening.bind(this))
```

or

```
this.server.on('listening', (e) => this.onListening(e))
```